# Cancelling progressdialog and asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, cancellation

I am displaying a cancelable progress dialog while an asynctask is running. When I press the back button, I want both the dialog to disappear, but also to cancel the running async task.
**The problem is: The dialog-instance is not known to the asynctask, so I cant't cancel the dialog after the asynctask has been cancelled.**

Currently it is only cancelled after I pushed the back button twice.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: post your code  :) buddy

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog boxes have an `onDismissed` [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29), use that to kill of the async task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ProgressDialog callback on cancel:

```
this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
this.dialog.setCancelable(true);
this.dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        // cancel AsyncTask
        cancel(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that my dialog instance is not known to the asynctask, so I can't use onCancel to cancel the asynctask.

Comment: Why don't you start your progress dialog into the AsyncTask?